# XML custom DataSet

Tags: .net, dataset, xmldocument

I have quite a lot of code that uses DataSet objects to load/save/manipulate data.
I want to improve performance of an exphansive caching-serialalizing process, by working with xml - instead of a dataset object. All changes I'm going to do should support the existing code syntax, for Example:

```
    count =MyDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    foreach(DataColumn c in MyDataset.Tables[0].Columns)
```

should Become:

```
    count =MyXmlDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    foreach(XDataColumn c in MyXmlDataset.Tables[0].Columns)
```

Before I build this myself, do you know of any existing library that immitates DataSet exactly and can be initialized from a DataSet?